# What should be the activaiton function for Neural Network in case of regression?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

My question is based on the understanding from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYbVFhK_olY&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v&index=43

In Neural Network a Neuron is activated by a threshold(activation) function, which in the above example is a sigmoid function. For regression problems do we need an activation function?
regards
Souvik

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It requires activation function in neural network regression too. If one is regressing neural network to the continuous range output, sigmoid like function can be used as activation functions. Avoid threshold-like activation function. Apart from output node, it will also require to have activation function across all the intermediate nodes of input and hidden layers.

Answer (score 0):

For the hidden layers, you should use Relu and don't use activation function for the output layer.

Please check this document: [Linear Regression](https://deeplearning4j.org/linear-regression)

Answer (score 0):

let's get some terminology clear:
by "regression" we usually refer to the simplest model where each of the independent variables have a parameter, and we multiply the variable with the parameter. In linear regression we stop there, with a continuous output. in logistic regression we also use an "activation function", probably the sigmoid, to get the output to be in the range (0,1), and then we can use a threshold (like x>0.5) to decide whether the output is 0 or 1.

So regession is like a neural network with 0 hidden layers.

Now I assume that what you meant is that you want the neural network to have a continuous output, like linear regression. so naturally we don't want to use any "distorting" function on the output layer.

However, we do want to use an activation function on the neurons in the hidden layers. the reason behind this is that we want the network to be able to break the linearity - so the network will be able to do something more interesting than just multiplying the variables by different parameters, allow it to combine them and different ways. The idea is to allow the network to simulate any function, even non linear ones.

So which activation should we choose to break the linearity? there are numerous options... sigmoid, tanh, relu, leaky-relu, elu, and many many more. the most common one today is relu, but this can change... it's mostly an empirical study of which ones work best and allow for the fastest learning. And it is up to the neural network architect to decide which function they want to use. As you get to know more of these functions and their pros and cons you'll be able to try a few for every problem and see what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So to have a continuous range in the output we can have a function like bias+weight*x and then apply one of the options(relu,leaky-relu) as applicable as an activation function in the hidden layers? And won't apply this on the final output, so that the result is continuous and can be used to calculate errors with the actual output. Is the understanding correct?

Comment: yap. activations only in the hidden layers, bias+weight*x as usual.